# Visualisation of vortex flows

Tags: fluid-dynamics, turbulence, vortex, visualization

Are there examples of vortex flows (eg: von Karman vortex street or large eddies) which are visualized in a way apart from displaying where the mass is displayed? I can imagine there to be a display based on velocity. But is there a display based on pressure?

From what I have seen, in a display of the vortex street, you can see how a mass of fluid is swirled around and eventually detached from a body, but that information isn't really useful quantitatively. Is it possible to find previous work where someone has measured velocity/forces/pressure around the vortex, is it possible and will a quantitative measurement help in any way?

Comment: Many vortex flows are (quasi) two dimensional, in which case a stream function $\psi$ can be defined and contours of $\psi$ = constant can be plotted. This is a very common way to visualize these flows.

Comment: Interest only - 4th photo down [here](http://azatlasz.hu/2014/07/kina_vietnam_konfliktus) - I took this photo in 2009.

Answer (score 1):

There are many research papers discussing what you are interested in. Even googling will give results, if you are specific enough. I'm sure there are a lot of papers where pressures and velocities are used to display the vortex.

Temperatures can also be used to visualize the vortex street: [This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IDeGDFZSYo8) shows this kind of flow visualization well.

Yet, the temperature contours don't really indicate the direction of rotation of the vortex. Another way, is using the [Vorticity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorticity) contours. this is perhaps the most useful way to do so, since it also indicates the direction of rotation of the vortex. [This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=usjIuIjO4Nw) shows the vorticity contours.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_t5tCrGMIyY This is a movie showing the pressure. Of course with numerical simulations you can relatively easily obtain all this information.